# How to rename field from object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 5.
I have "fake back-end" (array of items).
My case:
I'm waiting for the following structure of object:

```
id: number,
title: string
```

But, Back-End sends me wrong structure:

```
id: number,
name: string.
```

I need to receive data from back-end, and if field name (in my case "name" is wrong, should be "title") is wrong, I should RENAME field and return valid object.

P.S. I have interface and class

Comment: you can add new property during response and assign the value to the new property `(response) => {
   response.title = response.name
}`

Comment: and also if you're the one who maintain the backend then you can change directly the response object from the server (but not recommended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice on large apps where you don't have much control over the backend is to create a mapper for each response type you expect.

For example you make an http request to retrieve a list of cars from your backend.
When you retrieve the response, you pass the data to a specific mapping function.

```
class CarMapper {

    // map API to APP
    public serverModelToClientModel(apiModel: CarApiModel): CarAppModel {
        const appModel = new CarAppModel(); // your Car constructor
        // map each property
        appModel.id = apiModel.id_server;
        appModel.name = apiModel.title;
        return appModel; // and return YOUR model
    }

}
```

This way on the client side you always have the correct data model. And you adapt on any model change made on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an object has name key and then create another object with title

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty("name")){
  var newObj = {
    id: obj.id,
    title: obj.name
  };
}
obj = newObj;
```